# Reconciling complex TypeScript function overloading with dev (typings) experience

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript-typings

TypeScript provides function overloading that is interpreted by the compiler in the following manner (from the [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)):

> In order for the compiler to pick the correct typecheck, it follows a similar process to the underlying JavaScript. It looks at the overload list, and proceeding with the first overload attempts to call the function with the provided parameters. If it finds a match, it picks this overload as the correct overload. For this reason, its customary to order overloads from most specific to least specific.

Now take, for example, the function overloading used by `Promise.all()` found in [lib.es6.d.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts):

```
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>, T10 | PromiseLike<T10>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

These typings are clearly written in such a way that developers are given the **most complete and accurate** typing for the result of calling `Promise.all()` as possible (to the extent of a 10-element tuple).

If I call `Promise.all([1, 'hello']);` it can then accurately tell me that the first element in the result is of type `number`, the second element is of type `string`, and that there are no further elements. This is great and super helpful.

If the tuple-defined function overloads were missing, my result would then show as being of type `Promise<(number | string)[]>` which is obviously less specific and therefore less helpful.

But while these definitions help add in some specificity that can be taken advantage of by the developer and the compiler, if we now consider what a developer will see when he types `Promise.all(` into a modern IDE:

[image: IDE Intellisense on typing Promise.all(]

You can see that the suggestion provided matches the ordering of the overloads, giving us the most verbose option first. To a developer trying out an API for the first time, seeing this would likely be jarring. The overload that needs to be listed first in typings in order to guarantee the correct matching order for the compiler might not match what would be best to show a developer attempting to use an API.

I am currently working on an API with a similar function overload structure of verbose listing of different length tuples for maximum specificity on the resulting value's type. At the same time, however, I would like the developer to see the most generic of the options in order to enable easier digestion of the API.

Using the example of `Promise.all`, I would want them to see the lowest definition of `all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;` instead of the mess shown above when they type the opening parenthesis.

This question extends beyond the language itself and also relates to tooling, but **is there a way to reconcile/separate out the function overloading order that affects the compiler and the ordering of overloads in Intellisense when a developer begins to use a function?**